# subl command and filepath from bash variable

Tags: bash, sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublimetext3

I can use `subl` command to open file on certain position in `sublime text 3` on `OS X 10.10`.

```
$ subl /Users/user/Library/Application\ Support/Sublime\ Text\ 3/Packages/makeTest/test/createFromPosition_test.py:29
```

But I cannot put file path and position in bash variable and open it in sublime:

```
$ param=/Users/user/Library/Application\ Support/Sublime\ Text\ 3/Packages/makeTest/test/createFromPosition_test.py:29
$ echo $param
/Users/user/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages/makeTest/test/createFromPosition_test.py:29
$ subl $param
```

In this case it opens file

```
/Users/user/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages/3/Packages/makeTest/test/createFromPosition_test.py
```

I don't know why my filepath is corrupted when I use bash variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wrap your path in double quotes and remove the forward slashes.  Then, wrap the variable in quotes when passing it to `subl`.

```
$ param="/Users/user/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages/makeTest/test/createFromPosition_test.py:29"

$ echo $param
/Users/user/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages/makeTest/test/createFromPosition_test.py:29

$subl "$param"
```

Comment: the same result: `echo $param` prints fine path but `subl $param` opens bad file.